# Order of operation in particular integral

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

If we have particular integral $y_p=\frac{f(x)}{(D-a)(D-b)}$,in that case are $\frac{1}{D-a}[\frac{f(x)}{D-b}]$ and $\frac{1}{D-b}[\frac{f(x)}{D-a}]$ the same? Meaning if we can operate on $f(x)$ with $D-b$ first and later the obtained result with $D-a$(same applies for the other case). Does the order of operation matter in such cases?

For example,if we want to evaluate $\frac{x}{D(D+7)}$,the 2nd approach mentioned above will be $\frac{1}{D+7}[\frac{x}{D}]=\frac{1}{D+7}\times \frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{1}{2×7}[1-\frac{D}{7}+\frac{D^2}{7^2}-\cdots](x^2)=\frac{1}{2×7}[x^2-\frac{2x}{7}+\frac{2}{7^2}]$.

But in the 1st approach we will get $\frac{1}{D}[\frac{x}{D+7}]=\frac{1}{7D}[1-\frac{D}{7}+\cdots]x=\frac{1}{7D}(x-\frac{1}{7})=\frac{1}{7}[\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x}{7}]$.

We used binomial expansion in both the approaches.Here,as we can see there is an extra $\frac{1}{343}$ term in the 2nd approach.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: @Gonçalo,could you kindly check the post now?I have added an example and I don't understand where I went wrong.

Comment: For constant coefficient, order is irrelevant. This is not true for variable coefficient.

Comment: @CameronWilliams,could you please elaborate by shedding light on the example?

Comment: @madness, the results in your example differ by a constant $C$, but $D(D+7)C=(D+7)DC=0$, so both results are correct.

Comment: @Gonçalo,actually the original problem was $(D^2+D-12)y=e^{3x}x$,and the one I gave in the post is a sub problem of this main problem. Here our particular integral will be multiplied by $e^{3x}$. In that case,the two particular integrals will differ by $e^{3x} \times \frac{1}{343}$ which isn't a constant. Will both the approaches still be correct in that case? Also if you have time,a kind answer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In this last case, the particular solutions differ by a solution of the homogeneous equation. When you apply the differential operator $D^2+D-12$ to it, it vanishes.